# No qualifying bean of type found for dependency [Interface]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to write basic spring project. However, I have a big issue using `@Autowired through the Service. I didn't find the problem and got the error bellow:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.blackfirday.services.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Here is my code:

UserServiceInterface

```
package com.blackfirday.services;

import com.blackfriday.generated.User;

public interface UserService {
    public User userLogin(final String userId, final String userPassword);
}
```

UserServiceImpl

```
package com.blackfirday.services;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.blackfriday.dao.UserDao;
import com.blackfriday.generated.User;

@Service("userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired(required=true)
    @Qualifier(value="userDao")
    private UserDao userDao_;

    @Override
    public User userLogin(String userId, String userPassword) {
        // TODO: Varify the user password in the returned user object.
        return userDao_.getUserDetails(userId);
    }

}
```

UserDao Interface

```
package com.blackfriday.dao;

import com.blackfriday.generated.User;

public interface UserDao {
    public User getUserDetails(final String userId);
}
```

UserDao Impl

```
package com.blackfriday.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.blackfriday.generated.User;

@Repository("userDao")
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao {

    private final String connectionURL = "jdbc:msql://localhost:3306/blackfridaybank";
    private static final String DRIVER_PREFIX = "jdbc:apache:commons:dbcp:";

    @Override
    public User getUserDetails(String userId) {
        // TODO Make the database as centralized connection pool.
        Connection conn = null;
        User user = new User();
        try {
            conn = getConnection(connectionURL);
            conn.setAutoCommit(true);
            Statement stmnt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery("select * from user where id="+userId);

            while(rs.next()){
                user.setUserId(rs.getString("id"));
                user.setUserName(rs.getString("name"));
                user.setUserGender(rs.getString("gender"));
                user.setUserStatus(rs.getString("status"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try{
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return user;
    }

    private Connection getConnection(final String connectURL) throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(DRIVER_PREFIX + connectURL, "blackfriday", "blackfriday");
    }

}
```

UserServicesEndPoint

```
package com.blackfriday.webservices.endpoint;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.PayloadRoot;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.RequestPayload;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.ResponsePayload;

import com.blackfirday.services.UserService;
import com.blackfriday.generated.UserLoginRequest;
import com.blackfriday.generated.UserLoginResponse;

@Endpoint
public class UserServicesEndPoint {
    private static final String USER_LOGIN_REQUEST = "http://www.blackfridaybank.org/webservices/UserOperation";

    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserServicesEndPoint(UserService userService_i){
        userService = userService_i;
    }

    @PayloadRoot(localPart = "UserLoginRequest", namespace = USER_LOGIN_REQUEST)
    @ResponsePayload
    public UserLoginResponse getUserDetails(@RequestPayload UserLoginRequest request) {
        // 1.we need to make an instance of a response
        UserLoginResponse response = new UserLoginResponse();
        // 2.use the request data to in the services class and populated to
        // response
        response.setUserDetails(userService.userLogin(request.getUserId(), request.getPassword()));
        // 3.return a data populated response.
        return response;
    }

}
```

Startup class

```
package com.blackfriday.startup;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.blackfriday"})
public class Startup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Startup.class, args);
    }

}
```

Web Config

```
package com.blackfriday.startup;

import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.EnableWs;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition;
import org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema;
import org.springframework.xml.xsd.XsdSchema;

@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebSerivceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter{
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet (ApplicationContext context) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(context);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }

    @Bean(name="useroperation")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition (XsdSchema UserOperation) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("useroperationport");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://www.blackfridaybank.org/webservices/UserOperation");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(UserOperation);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema UserOperation() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("UserOperation.xsd"));
    }
    //adding the following method to return the correct xsd file before loaded to the soapui.
    @Bean
    public XsdSchema UserDetails() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("UserDetails.xsd"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you really have namespaces com.blackfriday and com.blackfirday? Sounds confusing.

Comment: sorry about the name space, I did actually use it as a namespace long time ago.

Comment: Please don't post the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491285/no-qualifying-bean-of-type-com-blackfirday-services-userservice-found-for-depe) twice within the hour! Remove one of them!.

Comment: Your config class scans all components under the package `com.blackfriday`. But your service is under the package `com.blackfirday`. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for your help. After I change that, the application run, but I getting the following error when I try to do a test with soap ui,    2016-04-08 15:49:10.793  WARN 22046 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.ws.server.EndpointNotFound           : No endpoint mapping found for [SaajSoapMessage {http://user.blackfridaybank.org}UserLoginRequest]

Comment: That is a completely different question. I don't know much about SOAP.

Comment: Your webservice endpoint is `http://www.blackfridaybank.org/webservices/UserOperation`. i believe you are testing with wrong endpoint URL from SOAP UI.